# Event KEYDOWN doesn't work when i press 's'

Tags: python

when i press 's' or 'w', the object won't move and it wouldn't say i pressed it:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Chicken ATTACK")
icon = pygame.image.load('pixil-frame-0.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

playerImg = pygame.image.load('farmer.png')
playerX = 60
playerY = 300
playerY_change = 0

def player(x,y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((80, 180, 50))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pygame.K_w:
                playerY -= -0.3
                print("w")
            if event.type == pygame.K_s:
                playerY += 0.3
                print("s")
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                playerY_change = 0

    playerY += playerY_change
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

i want the character to be moving up and down accordingly when i press 'w' or 's'

Comment: You have `event.type == pygame.K_w:` in key down and `event.key == pygame.K_w` in key up.

Answer (score 0):

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.type == pygame.K_w:
```

There's no way the second if statement could ever be true.

If `event.type` is equal to `pygame.KEYDOWN`, then *obviously* it will not be equal to `pygame.K_w`...

I think you meant to use `event.key`, not `event.type`, for the second if statement.